# How can I override a ModelAdmin value in Django when user makes a change in admin view?

Tags: django, overriding, admin

I am wondering if there is a way to override a value in the admin panel whenever a user makes a change?

**Scenario**:
I have a model with two fields, last_edited_by and last_edited_date.
what I would like to do is auto fill those two fields when the user goes to make changes to the entry.

**Attempt**:
here is some code that has allowed me to print the value of one of the fields, but there was no change in the admin panel even after applying a new value.

*admin.py*

```
class ProcessSheetRefAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        obj = super(ProcessSheetRefAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)

        if obj is not None:
            """
                attempting to update the value in last_edited_date, 
                but even after applying new value, the admin panel shows old value from 
                last database entry.
            """
            obj.last_edited_date = time.time() 

        if request.method == 'POST':
            print "admin post"

        return super(ProcessSheetRefAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

admin.site.register(ProcessSheetRefrence, ProcessSheetRefAdmin)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make change to your `obj` you need to  save it after that.

```
    if obj is not None:
        """
            attempting to update the value in last_edited_date, 
            but even after applying new value, the admin panel shows old value from 
            last database entry.
        """
        obj.last_edited_date = time.time()
        obj.save()
```